Minified React error #321 on Lazy Loaded Components
I have a react.js app which is added to our clients' websites as a widget. The clients' websites can be built on any tool e.g. wordress / angular / react etc.
We have two types of widgets: search and chat. I'm using a single repo for both, generate two separate builds, and host on aws s3.
On clients' sites we simply add a script and stylesheet of our build's index.js and index.css files hosted on s3. Until now, it worked just fine. Here's a sample build we have:

In my app, we can have multiple grids lazy loaded based on the client's need (e.g. in the above build you can see the trips grid being lazy loaded). We need this so that our build size doesn't increase too much, and on any individual client's site, only the grids relevant to that client are loaded.
Now this works fine when I include either the search build or the chat build on the clients' site. When I include links to both the builds on clients site, then I get an error when lazy loaded components are loaded.
Here's an example of a loader which is lazy loading trips grids:
import React, { Suspense, useMemo } from 'react'

// Utility function to lazy load the component
const getTripGridLazyLoaded = async organizationSlug => {
  switch (organizationSlug) {
    case 'clientA':
      return await import('./clientA/TripsGrid')
    case 'clientB':
      return await import('./clientB/TripsGrid')
    default:
      return await import('./common/TripsGrid')
  }
}

const TripsGridLoader = ({
  id,
  items,
  title,
  isLessThanLaptop,
  router,
  language,
  random_match,
  showRelevancyInfo,
  organizationSlug,
  itemsPerRow,
  itemsPerPage,
  isChatMode,
}) => {
  // Memoize the lazy-loaded component based on organizationSlug
  const TripGridLazyLoaded = useMemo(() => {
    if (!organizationSlug) return null
    return React.lazy(() => getTripGridLazyLoaded(organizationSlug))
  }, [organizationSlug])

  return (
    <>
      <Suspense fallback={<></>}>
        <TripGridLazyLoaded
          id={id}
          title={title}
          items={items}
          random_match={random_match}
          isLessThanLaptop={isLessThanLaptop}
          router={router}
          language={language}
          showRelevancyInfo={showRelevancyInfo}
          organizationSlug={organizationSlug}
          itemsPerRow={itemsPerRow}
          itemsPerPage={itemsPerPage}
          isChatMode={isChatMode}
        />
      </Suspense>
    </>
  )
}

export default TripsGridLoader

Here's a sample trip grid's code:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { GridWrapper, ItemsWrapper } from './style'
import TripItem from './TripItem'
import { GridTitle, GridSubtitle, ShowMoreCta } from './style'
import { TRANSLATIONS_TEXTS } from '../../../../utils/constants'

const TripsGrid = ({
  id,
  items,
  title,
  isLessThanLaptop,
  router,
  language,
  random_match,
  showRelevancyInfo,
  itemsPerRow,
  itemsPerPage,
  isChatMode,
}) => {
  const [currentIsLessThanLaptop, setIsCurrentIsLessThanLaptop] =
    useState(false)
  const [itemsToShow, setItemsToShow] = useState(0)
  const [gridId, setGridId] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLessThanLaptop) setIsCurrentIsLessThanLaptop(isLessThanLaptop)
  }, [isLessThanLaptop])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id !== gridId) {
      setGridId(id)
      setItemsToShow(itemsPerPage)
    }
  }, [id])

  if (!items?.length) return null

  const getItems = () => {
    const slicedItemsToShow = items.slice(0, itemsToShow)

    let itemsToReturn = slicedItemsToShow?.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <TripItem
          key={item.id || item.url + item?.name}
          isLessThanLaptop={currentIsLessThanLaptop}
          router={router}
          item={item}
          language={language}
          showRelevancyInfo={showRelevancyInfo}
          randomMatch={random_match}
          itemsPerRow={itemsPerRow}
        />
      )
    })

    return itemsToReturn
  }

  if (getItems().length) {
    return (
      <GridWrapper id='grid-wrapper-trip'>
        <GridTitle $padding={'0px 15px 0px 0px'} isChatMode={isChatMode}>
          {title}
        </GridTitle>
        <ItemsWrapper id='grid-trip-items-wrapper'>{getItems()}</ItemsWrapper>
        {itemsToShow < items.length ? (
          <ShowMoreCta
            onClick={() => {
              setItemsToShow(itemsToShow + itemsPerPage)
            }}
          >
            {TRANSLATIONS_TEXTS.show_more[language]}
          </ShowMoreCta>
        ) : null}
      </GridWrapper>
    )
  } else return null
}

export default TripsGrid


I get the following error when trips grids (or any other grids are lazy loaded) Also, these errors sometimes seem to occur randomly.

I've looked into it, and spent hours. As per the documentation here, it happens due to incorrect hook calls or react version mismatch errors.

I've already checked that react version is the same on app load time and lazy loaded components' loading time by logging console.log(React.version)
Also, the error not being there when just one of the two widgets search or chat is used is confusing.
I've added the code. It doesn't look like I have any incorrect hook calls

If I do npm ls react to see if I've multiple versions of react in my app then I get a single version. Here's the output:

Note that it also works just fine when I don't lazy load trips grids (or any other grids) like this:
import React, { useMemo } from 'react'
import Common from './common/TripsGrid'
import ClientA from './clientA/TripsGrid'
import ClientB from './clientB/TripsGrid'

const TripsGridLoader = ({
  id,
  items,
  title,
  isLessThanLaptop,
  router,
  language,
  random_match,
  showRelevancyInfo,
  organizationSlug,
  itemsPerRow,
  itemsPerPage,
  isChatMode,
}) => {
  // Memoize the lazy-loaded component based on organizationSlug
  const TripGridLazyLoaded = useMemo(() => {
    if (!organizationSlug) return null
    switch (organizationSlug) {
      case 'clientA':
        return ClientA
      case 'clientB':
        return ClientB
      default:
        return Common
    }
  }, [organizationSlug])

  return (
    <>
      <TripGridLazyLoaded
        id={id}
        title={title}
        items={items}
        random_match={random_match}
        isLessThanLaptop={isLessThanLaptop}
        router={router}
        language={language}
        showRelevancyInfo={showRelevancyInfo}
        organizationSlug={organizationSlug}
        itemsPerRow={itemsPerRow}
        itemsPerPage={itemsPerPage}
        isChatMode={isChatMode}
      />
    </>
  )
}

export default TripsGridLoader

Can anyone please point me to the right direction?

Hey I had this issue too. Any luck on this?

@ChrisKing I wasn't able to figure out the issue and is temporarily importing components without lazy loading. Let me know incase you find some solution to this.

The issue was the actual setup of the project. The problem is that it was importing itself. One with a unique hash file-139123.js and then inside it would call it's non-hash self of file.js
I had to modify vite/tsconfig/entrypoints so that it wouldn't import itself and there is only one file generated.
